# Installing Kile and linking with Mactex

Tags: mac, mactex, kile

I have been trying to use Kile in Mac OS Sierra and link it with Mactex. I have gone through several instructions over the internet but still could not do it. Most of the instructions are for older versions of mac and didn't work with this one. I am new to Mac environment as well as Kile so any guidance will be greatly helpful. Here's what I could do so far:
I had installed xcode earlier using

```
xcode-select install
```

I have installed fink for Sierra using the script in the link:
             https://github.com/fink/scripts/blob/master/srcinstaller/Install%20Fink.tool

I have installed kile using fink with the command:

```
fink install kile-kde4-mac
```

Other than that I also have installed MacTex from

http://www.tug.org/mactex/

Now whenever I start Kile, it shows a message:

"No editor component found. Please check your KDE installation"

I am not able to figure out what is needed here and also how I can link kile to Mactex.

Thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 1):

As for the part of your question regarding "No editor component found", try to install:

```
fink install katepart4-mac
```

That should solve your error message and get Kile up and running.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!